# How to solve the circular import error in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I know the error is probably due to circular import error but not having much knowledge about it I am not able to correct it. I have tried using the methods given in similar questions but couldn't resolve it.The project has two apps consult and main and I need to import their models into each other,

consult/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from main.models import Customer


class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="SkinCare")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    image = models.FileField(blank=True, default=None)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    deltatime = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.time)


class Reply(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=10000000000)
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislike = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    deltatime = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.time)
```

main/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from consult.models import Question, Reply


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skin_type = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    hair_type = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    bookmarked = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

When I run try to migrate the appps the following error comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Nikhil Khandelwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-
py3.5.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_
command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Nikhil Khandelwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-
py3.5.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Nikhil Khandelwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py3.5.egg\django\__init__.py", line 27, 
in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Nikhil Khandelwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py3.5.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 
108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\Nikhil Khandelwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py3.5.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 
199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Nikhil Khandelwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in 
_call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\New folder\WebD\zerovey\consult\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from main.models import Customer
  File "C:\New folder\WebD\zerovey\main\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from consult.models import Question, Reply
ImportError: cannot import name 'Question'
```

Please answer considering that I am a beginner in Django, Thanking you in Advance :)

Comment: Please, add traceback of an error.

Comment: [http://dpaste.com/2FBKXMC](http://dpaste.com/2FBKXMC)

Comment: don't import the models directly, import the app only exa - `import main` then access the models exa - `main.models.Customer`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `to='<app_lable>.<Model Name>'` in Foreignkey and ManytoMany Fields

Remove import models from file add foreignkey and manytomany fields in model like i did in below code.`to='consult.Question'`
When we create migrations from makemifration command that use hardcode model name in migration file, So use same way to write Foreignkey and Manytomany field

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django.db import models
class Customer(models.Model): 
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True) 
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skin_type = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    hair_type = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    bookmarked = models.ManyToManyField(to='consult.Question')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: 4 Years Later I Benefited From This Answer.
Kudos to you @neeraj-kumar

Comment: Can confirm. 5 years later, this answer still works with circular import issues. Sometimes you have a ManyToMany relation.

Comment: Can confirm, 6 years later, this answer still works for circular import errors.

Comment: Great solution, still working in 2023.  I struggle to find a documentation reference for it in the django docs.

Comment: In fact the "to=" is not necessary.
@MiloPersic "This sort of reference, called a lazy relationship, can be useful when resolving circular import dependencies between two applications."
From the docs about foreign keys: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your imports into this:
in consult/models.py

```
import main.models.Customer
```

in main/models.py

```
import consult.models.Question
import consult.models.Reply
```

Then instead of `Customer` you use `main.models.Customer` and instead of `Question` or `Reply` you use `import consult.models.Question` and `consult.models.Reply`

Comment: I tried using your suggestion @omu_negru but got the following error :-[http://dpaste.com/1MZ9N6R](http://dpaste.com/1MZ9N6R)

Comment: I also tried from "main import models as mm" but it gave the error "AttributeError: module 'consult.models' has no attribute 'Question'"

Comment: try dropping the `as mm` and then use the full qualified import path and tell me if it works

Comment: removing mm leads to errors as now two models have been imported-from django.db import models and from main import models

Answer (score 3):

Another way to resolve circular imports is to do:

```
from django.apps import apps
MyModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyModel')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this remove from main.models import Customer
and in the class

```
class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey("main.Customer",related_name="customerQuestion", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Reply(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("main.Customer",related_name="customerReply", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```