# ImportError: Could not import 'users.authenticate.jwt_response_payload_handler' for API setting

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-jwt

Set custom return error when using rest framework jwt token verification，ImportError: Could not import 'users.authenticate.jwt_response_payload_handler' for API setting 'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER'.

users.authenticate

```
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):

    return {
        'code': status.HTTP_200_OK,
        'data': token,
        'message': 'Success'
    }
```

setting

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'users.authenticate.jwt_response_payload_handler'
}
```

At that time commented out 'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'users.authenticate.jwt_response_payload_handler' can successfully run to obtain token

Traceback

```
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
    packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 177, in import_from_string
       return import_string(val)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\lk\r\python\r\users\authenticate.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rest_framework_jwt.views import ObtainJSONWebToken
ImportError: cannot import name 'ObtainJSONWebToken' from partially initialized module 'rest_framework_jwt.views' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_jwt\views.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 406, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 587, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 580, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\lk\r\python\r\r\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('users/', include('users.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\lk\r\python\r\users\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_jwt\views.py", line 12, in <module>
    jwt_response_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 225, in __getattr__
    val = perform_import(val, attr)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 166, in perform_import
    return import_from_string(val, setting_name)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 180, in import_from_string
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Could not import 'users.authenticate.jwt_response_payload_handler' for API setting 'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER'. ImportError: cannot import name 'ObtainJSONWebToken' from partially initialized module 'rest_framework_jwt.views' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_jwt\views.py).
```

Answer (score 0):

## Circular Import Problem

Here you can understand what is [circular import problem](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/).

Here is one way to [solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601550/how-to-solve-the-circular-import-error-in-django)

Though in my experience I first check by commenting out the lines where this circular import is happening.
In your case according to the error traceback the problem is happening in here

```py
File "D:\lk\r\python\r\users\authenticate.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rest_framework_jwt.views import ObtainJSONWebToken
```

and here

```py
File "D:\lk\r\python\r\users\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
```

I think this `ObtainJSONWebToken` is imported in views and in urls.
You have to resolve this. This can be done by solution provided above.

Comment: The problem has been solved, thank you.